# Trouble running Flask application

Tags: python, linux, flask, pip, virtualenv

I have created a virtual environment specifying python3

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 flask_tut
$ source flask_tut/bin/activate
```

created a file named hello.py containing:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

and, while in my working directory containing hello.py, enter:

```
(flask_tut) $ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
(flask_tut) $ python -m flask run
```

However, this yields errors that I am struggling with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/Envs/flask_tut/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/matt/Envs/flask_tut/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 478, in main
...
ImportError: cannot import name 'flask'
```

This is weird to me, I have installed flask as `pip list` indicates I have Flask (0.11.1). Others have solved similar issues by using python 3 which I am using as `python --version` shows I am using Python 3.5.1+

If anyone can provide help that would be excellent. 
I am using Linux Mint if that makes a difference.

Edit:
After trying 100 different things, I just deleted my virtual environment, and hello.py, created a new virtual environment, working directory and script, and there are no problems. I will post if I get down to the root issue as I suspect this may happen to others running through the Flask tutorial.

Comment: Did you install flask into your virtualenv using pip?

Comment: @Suever , yes I have, after running the source command!

Comment: What if you run python and then call `import flask` from the prompt?

Comment: I will try, thank you! It looks like starting over again worked out for me, but am unsure of what happened there.

Comment: What is wrong with `python ./hello.py`?